# Proving left inverse for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Taken from Artin's book, need to prove that an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ (where $m < n$) has no left inverse. A hint given is to compare matrix $A$ to an $n \times n$ matrix obtained by taking $A$ and adding ($n-m$) zero rows to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that if you had such a left inverse, that is, an $n \times m$ matrix $B$ with $BA = I_n$, you could add $n-m$ zero rows to the bottom of $A$ and $n-m$ zero columns to the right of $B$ to get two $n \times n$ matrices $A'$ and $B'$ such that $B'A' = BA = I_n$. But for instance $A'$ cannot be invertible because its rows are linearly dependent.

More conceptually, the matrix $A$ represents a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ from a higher-dimensional space to a lower-dimensional space, and such a map cannot be injective (have a left inverse) because an injective linear map preserves linear independence.